How to prove this inequality involving trigamma functions?
While solving a problem I succeeded to reduce it to the following inequality:
$$
\forall \{a,b,z\in\mathbb R_+,\ a\ne b\}:\quad 0<\frac1{a-b}\int_0^\infty\frac{t(a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})}{1-e^{-t}}dt<\frac1z,
$$
which holds by numerical evidence. The integral can be presented as a linear combination of trigamma functions.
The left inequality is rather simple since the integral can be expressed as
$$
\frac1{a-b}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left[\frac1{\left(z+\frac ka\right)^2}-\frac1{\left(z+\frac kb\right)^2}\right]
$$
but I have problems with the right one. I will appreciate any hint. A proof by elementary means is preferred.

For the right inequality.
WLOG, assume that $a > b$.
Let $t_0 = \frac{\ln(a^2) - \ln(b^2)}{z(a - b)}$.
Then, $a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt} \ge 0$ on $(0, t_0]$,
and $a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt} \le 0$ on $[t_0, \infty)$.
It suffices to prove that
$$I_1 + I_2 < \frac{1}{z}$$
where
$$I_1 := \frac1{a-b}\int_0^{t_0}\frac{t(a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})}{1-e^{-t}}\,\mathrm{d}t, $$
and $$I_2 := \frac1{a-b}\int_{t_0}^\infty\frac{t(a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})}{1-e^{-t}}\,\mathrm{d}t.$$
Let
$$f(t) := \frac{t}{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-t}}.$$
We have $f''(t) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t}(t\mathrm{e}^{-t} + 2\mathrm{e}^{-t} + t - 2)}{(1 - \mathrm{e}^{-t})^3} \ge 0$ for all $t\ge 0$. Thus, $f(t)$ is convex on $t \ge 0$.
Using the convexity of $f(t)$ on $t \ge 0$, we have, for all $0 \le t \le t_0$,
$$f(t) \le \frac{f(t_0) - f(0)}{t_0 - 0}(t - 0) + f(0). \tag{1}$$
Thus, we have
$$
 I_1 \le \frac1{a-b}\int_0^{t_0} (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})\left[\frac{f(t_0) - f(0)}{t_0 - 0}t + f(0)\right]\,\mathrm{d}t. \tag{2}
$$
Using the convexity of $f(t)$ on $t \ge 0$, we have, for all $t \ge 0$,
$$f(t) \ge f(t_0) + f'(t_0)(t - t_0). \tag{3}$$
Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
 I_2 &= \frac1{a-b}\int_{t_0}^\infty\frac{t(a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})}{1-e^{-t}}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
 &\le \frac1{a-b}\int_{t_0}^\infty (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})[f(t_0) + f'(t_0)(t - t_0)]\,\mathrm{d}t. \tag{4}
\end{align*}
Using (2) and (4), we have
\begin{align*}
 I_1 + I_2 &\le \frac1{a-b}\int_0^{t_0} (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})\left[\frac{f(t_0) - f(0)}{t_0 - 0}t + f(0)\right]\,\mathrm{d}t\\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \frac1{a-b}\int_{t_0}^\infty (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})[f(t_0) + f'(t_0)(t - t_0)]\,\mathrm{d}t\\[6pt]
 &= \frac1{a-b}\int_0^{t_0} (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})\left[f'(t_0)t + f(0)\right]\,\mathrm{d}t\\[6pt]
 &\qquad - \frac1{a-b}\int_0^{t_0} (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})\left(f'(t_0) - \frac{f(t_0) - f(0)}{t_0 - 0}\right)t\,\mathrm{d}t\\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \frac1{a-b}\int_{t_0}^\infty (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})[f'(t_0)t + f(0)]\,\mathrm{d}t\\[6pt]
 &\qquad - \frac1{a-b}\int_{t_0}^\infty (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})[f(0) - f(t_0) + f'(t_0)t_0]\,\mathrm{d}t\\[6pt]
 &= f'(t_0)\cdot \frac1{a-b}\int_0^\infty (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})\,t\,\mathrm{d}t \\[6pt]
 &\qquad + f(0)\cdot \frac1{a-b}\int_0^\infty (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})\,\mathrm{d}t \\[6pt]
 &\qquad - \left(f'(t_0) - \frac{f(t_0) - f(0)}{t_0 - 0}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{a-b} \int_0^{t_0} (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})t\,\mathrm{d}t\\[6pt]
 &\qquad - \left(f'(t_0) - \frac{f(t_0) - f(0)}{t_0 - 0}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{a-b}\int_{t_0}^\infty (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})t_0\,\mathrm{d}t\\[6pt]
 &= \frac{1}{z} - \left(f'(t_0) - \frac{f(t_0) - f(0)}{t_0 - 0}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{a-b} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-bzt_0} - \mathrm{e}^{-azt_0}}{z^2}\\[6pt]
 &< \frac{1}{z} \tag{5}
\end{align*}
where we use
$\frac1{a-b}\int_0^\infty (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})\,t\,\mathrm{d}t = 0$, and $\frac1{a-b}\int_0^\infty (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})\,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{z}$, and $f'(t_0) - \frac{f(t_0) - f(0)}{t_0 - 0}\ge 0$ (by the convexity of $f(t)$ on $t\ge 0$), and
$$\int_0^{t_0} (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})t\,\mathrm{d}t
+ \int_{t_0}^\infty (a^2e^{-azt}-b^2e^{-bzt})t_0\,\mathrm{d}t
= \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-bzt_0} - \mathrm{e}^{-azt_0}}{z^2}.$$
We are done.

$\def\d{\,{\rm d}}$
This is intended as an extended comment to the brilliant answer of River Li to enlighten the idea behind the proof and to give on this basis a simpler solution to original question. Hopefully this comment is useful.
Assume that we need to find the bounds on an integral
$$
I=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x)w(x)\d x,
$$
where $f(x)$ is a positive function (all variables and functions are assumed to be real).
If $w(x)$ changes sign on $(x_1,x_2)$ it separates the integration interval into regions $X_+$ where $w(x)>0$ and $X_-$ where $w(x)<0$.
Let $f_-(x)$ and $f_+(x)$ be such positive functions of $x$ that:
$$
f_-(x)\begin{cases}
\le f(x),& x\in X_+\\
\ge f(x),& x\in X_-\\
\end{cases},\quad
f_+(x)\begin{cases}
\ge f(x),& x\in X_+\\
\le f(x),& x\in X_-\\
\end{cases}.
$$
Then
$$I_-=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f_-(x)w(x)\d x\le I\le\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f_+(x)w(x)\d x=I_+.$$
For the original problem with $$f(x)=\frac x{1-e^{-x}},\quad w(x)=\frac{a^2e^{-atx}-b^2e^{-btx}}{a-b}$$
the linear functions:
$$
f_-(x)=\frac{f(x_0)}{x_0}x,\quad f_+(x)=1+\frac{f(x_0)-1}{x_0}x,
$$
where $x_0$ is the only zero of the function $w(x)$, give immediately the required inequalities (the complicated function $f_+(x)$ of River Li gives in fact a better upper bound).

Rewrite the inequality as
\begin{align*}0<\frac{1}{a-b}\left(a^2\psi'(az)-b^2\psi'(bz)\right)<\frac{1}{z}\end{align*}
Wlog $a>b$. Set $A=az$, $B=bz$. Multiply everything by $(a-b)z^2$ to rewrite as
\begin{align*}0<A^2\psi'(A)-B^2\psi'(B)<(a-b)z=A-B\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}0<\frac{A^2\psi'(A)-B^2\psi'(B)}{A-B}<1\end{align*}
By applying mean value theorem to the function $z\mapsto z^2\psi'(z)$, the term in the middle is of the form $(z^2\psi'(z))'$ for some $z\in(A,B)$ so one must show for $z>0$
\begin{align*}0<(z^2\psi'(z))'<1\end{align*}
Note that
\begin{align*}(z^2\psi'(z))'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2nz}{(n+z)^3}\end{align*}
so the left side is trivial. To obtain the right side, one approach might be to use Euler-Maclaurin to estimate the sum. A faster way is to use the formula (cf. wikipedia article on digamma function)
\begin{align*}\psi(z)=\ln(z)-\frac{1}{2z}-\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{B_{2n}}{2nz^{2n}}+(-1)^{N+1}\frac{2}{z^{2N}}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{2N+1}dt}{(t^2+z^2)(e^{2\pi t}-1))}\end{align*}
One obtains
\begin{align*}(z^2\psi(z))'=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2n-1)B_{2n}}{z^{2n}}+(-1)^{N+1}T\end{align*}
where the term $T$ is a sum with positive coefficients of terms of the form $\frac{1}{z^k}\int_0^\infty$, where the integrand is nonnegative everywhere in all terms. So $T\geq0$. So if $N$ is even, one obtains an upper bound. For $N=2$, one obtains
\begin{align*}(z^2\psi'(z))'\leq1-\frac{1}{6z^2}+\frac{1}{10z^4}\end{align*}
One can see that the right side is $< 1$ for $z\geq1$. It remains to show numerically that for $0<z<1$, one has
\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2nz}{(n+z)^3}<1\end{align*}
If $z<\frac{3}{\pi^2}$, one has the bound $<\frac{3}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n^2}=1$. The case $0.3<z<1$ also shouldn't be too hard to tackle numerically. Say, split this interval into 70 intervals of the form $[x,x+0.01]$ (where $x=0.3,0.31,\dots,0.99$) and if $z\in[x,x+0.01]$ then use the estimate
\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2nz}{(n+z)^3}\leq(x+0.01)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{(n+x)^3}\end{align*}
so it will suffice to evaluate this expression in 70 points from $0.3$ to $0.99$.
